# Сертификат acme в traefik

Tags: letsencrypt, traefik

Подскажите. Как в traefik1.* связать несколько `entryPoint` с `[acme]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, этого сделать нельзя. `acme` в этой версии не приспособлен для этого. [Здесь](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2710) очень многие люди высказывают, что им этого не хватает.

При этом, как сделан этот функционал во второй версии также не ясно.